# use filter to do a listview search

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to use filter to do a listview search, but I get the error "FilterResults cannot be resolved to a type", and if I add 
"import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filter.FilterResults;" at the beginning, another error appears "The type android.widget.Filter.FilterResults is not visible", really don't know how to fix.
here is my recipeadapter:

```
     class RecipesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Recipe> implements Filterable{


         LayoutInflater inflater;
         ArrayList<Recipe> arraylist;

     public RecipesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recipe> arraylist) {
            super(context, R.layout.row_recipe, recipes);
            this.arraylist = arraylist;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if(itemView == null) {
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_recipe, parent, false);
            }

            final Recipe currentEvent = recipes.get(position);

            TextView recipeName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipename);
            recipeName.setText(currentEvent.name);

            TextView time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeContent);
            time.setText(currentEvent.created_at);


            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return super.getCount();
        }
    }       

 @Override
 public Filter getFilter() {
     Filter filter = new Filter() {

         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         @Override
         protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

             recipes = (ArrayList<Recipe>) results.values; // has the filtered values
             notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
         }

         private void notifyDataSetChanged() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
         protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
             FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
             ArrayList<Recipe> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<Recipe>();

             if (recipes == null) {
                 recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>(); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
             }

             /********
              * 
              *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
              *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
              *
              ********/
             if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                 // set the Original result to return  
                 results.count = recipes.size();
                 results.values = recipes;
             } else {
                 constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                 for (int i = 0; i < recipes.size(); i++) {
                     Recipe data = recipes.get(i);
                     if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                         FilteredArrList.add(data);
                     }
                 }
                 // set the Filtered result to return
                 results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                 results.values = FilteredArrList;
             }
             return results;
         }

        @Override
        public boolean onLoadClass(Class clazz) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
     };
     return filter;
 }
```

the ArrayList recipes has been declared out side the Recipesadapter.

Comment: Try to have only "import android.widget.Filter", and remove "import android.widget.Filter.FilterResults". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814681/java-import-error-the-type-android-widget-filter-filterresults-is-not-visible

Comment: if you have problems with import statement you probably will fail in implementing Filterable interface

Comment: @AB, I've see this link before, tried to remove "import android.widget.Filter.FilterResults" but get another error called "The import android.widget.Filter collides with another import statement" appears.

Comment: @pskink then what I should do with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I did it manually without using filter in a very easy way without using any extra click, just type in edit text and results are in the list view. List view elements changes according to the characters typed/removed in the edit text:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.examplesearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        final EditText search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        final ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        arraylist.add("Balvier");
        arraylist.add("Sudhier");
        arraylist.add("Abhinay");
        arraylist.add("Amit");
        arraylist.add("Dilip");
        final ArrayList<String> newArraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arraylist);

        newArraylist.clear();

        list1.setAdapter(adapter);
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                newArraylist.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                    if (search.getText().length() <= arraylist.get(i).length()) {
                        if (search
                                .getText()
                                .toString()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        (String) arraylist.get(i).subSequence(
                                                0, search.getText().length()))) {
                            newArraylist.add(arraylist.get(i).toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                        newArraylist);
                list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.examplesearch.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/search"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I noticed you added some strings to your arraylist, but my model is Recipe. it seems doesn't work for me. another two questions are: why do you have two arrayadapter object in your code; why  do you use newArraylist.clear() twice in your code?

Comment: i needed two arraylist and two adapters to keep all original data and searched data separated. I implemented it in the same scenario you posted in your code but manually, means you can implement this for custom adapters also in the same way. newArraylist.clear() should be called only inside onTextChanged() not twice.

Comment: get it. Could you show me your code in the same scenario? because I don't know what's wrong with my code. @Balvir Jha

Comment: I have followed your code and tried to modify my own. Now there is no compile error but I still cannot run it. @Balvir Jha